# i18next is undefined in react app

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next

I have just started using i18next package on my react app but I'm having a problem. I did 'yarn add i18next@7.1.3 --save' to install the package. And then in my component I did this:

```
import i18next from 'i18next'
// other imports...

// defining class
constructor(props){
  super(props)

  console.log(i18next.t('Wähle einen Titel für deinen Ratgeber'))
}
```

And in render method I'm doing this

```
<Explainer header={i18next.t('Was macht ein gutes Thema aus?')}>
   <GoodTitleExplainer/>
</Explainer>
```

So, on console, I am getting undefined and an error **The prop `header` is marked as required in `Explainer`, but its value is `undefined`**.

I have got it working in another project but I don't know what's the problem here. Help please.

Answer (score 1):

Did you init the i18next instance? https://www.i18next.com/getting-started.html#basic-sample

Further for using with react i highly recommend using react-i18next: https://react.i18next.com makes loading translations and usage a lot easier